# Is it possible to use ClearScript on Mac M1?

Tags: c#, macos, .net-6.0, clearscript

OS: Mac M1
Framework: .Net 6.0
IDE: Rider

NuGet packages:

- Microsoft.ClearScript (v7.2.1)
- Microsoft.ClearScript.V8 (v7.2.1)

My simple JavaScript REPL:

```
using Microsoft.ClearScript.V8;
using myConsole = System.Console;

var v8 = new V8ScriptEngine();
v8.AddHostType("myConsole", typeof(Console));

// JavaScript REPL
while (true)
{
    myConsole.WriteLine("> ");
    var expression = myConsole.ReadLine();
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(expression)) continue;
    if(expression.Equals("exit", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) Environment.Exit(0);
    try
    {
        _ = v8.Evaluate(expression);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        myConsole.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I can build it without any problems. But if I run my code I get the error. I see it can't find file `ClearScriptV8.osx-arm64.dylib`:

```
/Users/andrey/RiderProjects/ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1/bin/Debug/net6.0/ConsoleApp1
Unhandled exception. System.TypeLoadException: Cannot load ClearScript V8 library. Load failure information for ClearScriptV8.osx-arm64.dylib:
/Users/andrey/RiderProjects/ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1/bin/Debug/net6.0/runtimes/osx-arm64/native/ClearScriptV8.osx-arm64.dylib: Unable to load shared library '/Users/andrey/RiderProjects/ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1/bin/Debug/net6.0/runtimes/osx-arm64/native/ClearScriptV8.osx-arm64.dylib' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES environment variable: dlopen(/Users/andrey/RiderProjects/ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1/bin/Debug/net6.0/runtimes/osx-arm64/native/ClearScriptV8.osx-arm64.dylib, 0x0001): tried: '/Users/andrey/RiderProjects/ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1/bin/Debug/net6.0/runtimes/osx-arm64/native/ClearScriptV8.osx-arm64.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/ClearScriptV8.osx-arm64.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/ClearScriptV8.osx-arm64.dylib' (no such file)
/Users/andrey/RiderProjects/ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1/bin/Debug/net6.0/ClearScriptV8.osx-arm64.dylib: Unable to load shared library '/Users/andrey/RiderProjects/ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1/bin/Debug/net6.0/ClearScriptV8.osx-arm64.dylib' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES environment variable: dlopen(/Users/andrey/RiderProjects/ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1/bin/Debug/net6.0/ClearScriptV8.osx-arm64.dylib, 0x0001): tried: '/Users/andrey/RiderProjects/ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1/bin/Debug/net6.0/ClearScriptV8.osx-arm64.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/ClearScriptV8.osx-arm64.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/ClearScriptV8.osx-arm64.dylib' (no such file)
/System/ClearScriptV8.osx-arm64.dylib: Unable to load shared library '/System/ClearScriptV8.osx-arm64.dylib' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES environment variable: dlopen(/System/ClearScriptV8.osx-arm64.dylib, 0x0001): tried: '/System/ClearScriptV8.osx-arm64.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/ClearScriptV8.osx-arm64.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/ClearScriptV8.osx-arm64.dylib' (no such file)
   at Microsoft.ClearScript.V8.V8Proxy.LoadNativeLibrary(String baseName, String platform, String architecture, String extension)
   at Microsoft.ClearScript.V8.V8Proxy.LoadNativeAssembly()
   at Microsoft.ClearScript.V8.V8Proxy.OnEntityHolderCreated()
   at Microsoft.ClearScript.V8.SplitProxy.V8EntityHolder..ctor(String name, Func`1 acquireHandle)
   at Microsoft.ClearScript.V8.SplitProxy.V8IsolateProxyImpl..ctor(String name, V8RuntimeConstraints constraints, V8RuntimeFlags flags, Int32 debugPort)
   at Microsoft.ClearScript.V8.V8IsolateProxy.Create(String name, V8RuntimeConstraints constraints, V8RuntimeFlags flags, Int32 debugPort)
   at Microsoft.ClearScript.V8.V8Runtime..ctor(String name, V8RuntimeConstraints constraints, V8RuntimeFlags flags, Int32 debugPort)
   at Microsoft.ClearScript.V8.V8Runtime..ctor(String name, V8RuntimeConstraints constraints, V8RuntimeFlags flags)
   at Microsoft.ClearScript.V8.V8Runtime..ctor(String name, V8RuntimeConstraints constraints)
   at Microsoft.ClearScript.V8.V8ScriptEngine..ctor(V8Runtime runtime, String name, V8RuntimeConstraints constraints, V8ScriptEngineFlags flags, Int32 debugPort)
   at Microsoft.ClearScript.V8.V8ScriptEngine..ctor(String name, V8RuntimeConstraints constraints, V8ScriptEngineFlags flags, Int32 debugPort)
   at Microsoft.ClearScript.V8.V8ScriptEngine..ctor(String name, V8RuntimeConstraints constraints, V8ScriptEngineFlags flags)
   at Microsoft.ClearScript.V8.V8ScriptEngine..ctor(String name, V8RuntimeConstraints constraints)
   at Microsoft.ClearScript.V8.V8ScriptEngine..ctor()
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in /Users/andrey/RiderProjects/ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1/Program.cs:line 4

Process finished with exit code 134.
```

Is it possible to use ClearScript on Mac M1? If "yes" then how can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved. A solution was provided in the following GitHub issue: [here](https://github.com/microsoft/ClearScript/issues/352).

The solution is to use the `Microsoft.ClearScript.osx-arm64` package.